# Why setTimeout does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please See the code below.

SetTimeout should execute the seconf function after 100ms time. but first one has blocked second which is unexpected. Settimeout workd in Asynchronous way.

```
function funcOne(){
    console.log("FuncOne invoked")
    let i=0;
    while(i<10000000000){i++}
    console.log("Hello world")

}
function funcTwo(){
    console.log("FuncTwo invoked");
}

setTimeout(funcOne,0)   
setTimeout(funcTwo,100)
```

Output should be

FuncOne invoked

FuncTwo invoked

Hello World

But the Actual Output is

FuncOne invoked

HelloWorld

FuncTwo invoked.

Comment: Not quite sure why you think it would be "FuncOne invoked FuncTwo invoked Hello World"

Comment: Because second Function is executed after 100ms delay,but the first one takes around 10 second to complete it. SecondFunction should not be blocked and it should be executed after 100ms only.

Comment: The output is exactly as expected. Please read about the event loop. you will understand why this output shows.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript cannot run in separate threads*, so all your code is running in one thread. Anything that is "asynchronous" is just various pieces of code taking turns to run. The Javascript engine will never interrupt one function because another is scheduled to run at a given moment, this is something you need to take care of yourself.

So in your case, `funcOne` is executed (completely), even though that takes more than 100 ms, then the timeouts are checked and since `funcTwo` is due to run, it then gets executed (completely).

*well, kind of maybe with workers, but it's not pretty.

Comment: Indeed, i would like to add that javascript engine can't perform asynchronous as you mentioned. But you can write them anyway, because outer world perform them for javascript (eg: Browser API). How? Javascript send your async request to browsers api, that can perform async call with a callback, when code is executed, callback updates javascripts **Call Stack**. Also **NOTE:** `setTimeout` is performed by **Browser API**

Answer (score 0):

The second setTimeout wont be called until your while loop finishes

So you got this order

First timeout called
FuncOne invoked
While loop finishes
Hello World

Second timeout called, after 100ms funcTwo invoked